# How can I crash my Flutter app in debug mode on a simulator?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, crashlytics

I'm trying to implement crashlytics in my project but need to crash my app - I dont have a physical device to build a release version to so I need to crash the debug version.
I've tried throw exception() and Crashlytics.instance.crash() but the exceptions are caught by Flutter and the app doesnt actually crash. How can I force a crash?

Comment: [crashlytics test-implementation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation) guide might help in creating a crash for testing

Comment: It sounds like you're always building in debug mode. Try creating an artifact via `flutter build [apk/ios] --release` and installing it manually.

Comment: @AlexMeuer you can't install release artifacts on the simulator unfortunately. I got it to work, just didn't post the solution because I don't know if it will be very helpful - basically all I did was close out the app and restart it, then throw the exception and it worked. Maybe being attached to the debugger was messing with it? I don't really know...